# Data not saved with redux react for android

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I probably missunderstood how does redux works but my datas are not saved into the store and i quit et re-open the app. Everything works perfectly when i keep my app open (I can add sessions, exercices...) and everything is saved but when i close it there's no data. Do i've to write some code to receive the store data ?
Here's my code :
Home.js (home page) :

```
import React from 'react'
import { FlatList, View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import Session from './Session'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import GlobalStyle from '../helpers/GlobalStyle'

class Home extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    _displaySessionDetails = (idSession) => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate("SessionDetails", { 
            session: this._filterItems(idSession, this.props.globalSessions), 
        })
    }

    _filterItems = (recherche, enssemble) => {
        return enssemble.find(item => item.id == recherche);
    }

    _addSession = () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate("NewSession")
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={[styles.container, GlobalStyle.container]}>
                <FlatList
                    data={ this.props.globalSessions }
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
                    renderItem={({item}) => <Session session={item} displayDetailsForSession={ this._displaySessionDetails } />}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity style={GlobalStyle.bottom_btn} onPress={() => { this._addSession() }}>
                    <Text style={GlobalStyle.bottom_btn_content}>+</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }
}  

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        globalSessions: state.globalSessions
    }
}
  
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Home)
```

ConfigureStore.js :

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import reducerSession from './Reducer/ReducerSession'

export default createStore(reducerSession)
```

ReducerSession.js :

```
 const initialState = { globalSessions: [] }

function reducerSession (state = initialState, action) {
    let nextState
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ADD_SESSION':
            console.log("Add session")
            nextState = {
                ...state,
                globalSessions: [...state.globalSessions, action.value]
            }
            return nextState || state
        case 'UPDATE_SESSION':
            if(action.subtype == 'ADD_EXERCICE') {
                console.log("Add exercice : " + action.value.exercice.repetition + " x " + action.value.exercice.title)
                nextState = {
                    ...state,
                    globalSessions: [...state.globalSessions]
                }
                let session = nextState.globalSessions.find((item) => item.id == action.value.id)
                session.exercices.push(action.value.exercice)
            } else if(action.subtype == 'DELETE_EXERCICE') {
                console.log("Delete exercice (session: " + action.value.idSession + ", exo: " + action.value.idExo + ")")
                nextState = {
                    ...state,
                    globalSessions: [...state.globalSessions]
                }
                let session = nextState.globalSessions.find((item) => item.id == action.value.idSession)
                session.exercices = session.exercices.filter((item) => item.id != action.value.idExo)
            }
            return nextState || state
        case 'DELETE_SESSION':
            console.log("Delete session")
            nextState = {
                ...state,
                globalSessions: [...state.globalSessions.filter((item) => item.id != action.value.id)]
            }
            return nextState || state
        default: 
            return state
    }
}

export default reducerSession
```

and app.js :

```
import React from 'react'
import Navigation from './navigation/Navigation'
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import Store from './Store/configureStore'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={Store}>
      <StatusBar  translucent backgroundColor="transparent" barStyle='light-content' />
      <Navigation />
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

Every should be there, i hope i did not forget some code.
Thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redux is an in-memory store, by default it does not persist it's data anywhere, which means it will start from zero after you reopen your app.

You probably want to add something like [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) for saving & loading the state to your device.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what i was looking for !
I just have two questions then :
- What redux is used for ?
- Is this normal that date objects are not saved correctly on persist redux store ?

Comment: Redux is mostly a pattern for data-flow within your application and making that data available everywhere - and the code binding that pattern together, in the case of a react appliaction also making sure the right components rerender at the right time. I recommend you read up on the official tutorials, as most external tutorials are horribly outdated (modern redux looks very different from your code): https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index

As for redux-persist not saving dates: Dates cannot be serialized & deserialized automatically as JSON. I recommend you store timestamps instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to figure out how to *store* state between sessions, maybe the ["Sending Data with Thunks" section](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic#sending-data-with-thunks) of the Redux documentation will help. It's part of a tutorial which should leave you with a pretty good idea of how to integrate async API calls with reducers.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser, i'm not trying to configure sessions but to stock sport data (day of exercice, what exercices...). Datas should be stocked locally to allow users to see their evolution

Comment: Sorry, I meant "session" generally, like "a time a person is using the app", not something that has to be specifically configured. Redux will not store anything by itself if the app is restarted, so you'll need something which either uses on-device storage (maybe redux-persist, mentioned in @phry's comment) or a server-side persistent storage setup.